# Wordpress user login causes all plugins to fail

Tags: wordpress

When users register and log in to my wordpress site, it seems that users with the .nl (Netherlands) email address (being used as the username) somehow causes none of the plugins to trip.

I put some debugging around two of them on a particular page, and although the sidebar initiates and makes room for the plugins, the sidebar contents are empty (both visually and in the DOM).

I have tested other email extensions, .com, .net, .ca, .cz, .it, and .au and all of them work normally. But all of my email tests ending in .nl are causing this issue.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Wordpress 3.2.1 (latest)

Comment: Could you give us some idea of which plugins you're using?

Comment: I have actually disabled all but 1 and I am still having the same results. The only one I kept alive was my own custom one. I also tried disabling that one and enabling another, still experiencing the failure. Conclusion: it is not the plugin itself.

Comment: If you use the default twenty ten theme do things work? If the default theme works then what theme are you using?

Comment: Which roles have the _.nl_ users? Can you tell the plugins and theme your are using? Unfortunately, without this information nor a bounty can help you.

Comment: The problem with the wordpress admin area is often the memory configuration. Did you try to raise the PHP memory for your word press installation? I could catch these errors by doing so.

Comment: @mrtsherman yes, they work just fine in Twenty Ten theme... didnt think to try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your login page customized? have you tried changing the theme?

There some good advice on the below page which you might find useful, if you haven't already checked it yet.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

The one i'm referring to in particular is on New Login File section inside the above link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble#New_Login_File

Also something that you might find helpful:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/allowing-registration-with-the-email-as-username

P.S:- I'm starting to believe wordpress wasn't meant to allow any user to register with such usernames by default 'email@domain.com'. What i've seen is people mostly use plugins to do this, and also as far i've researched about this topic - it is considered a bad idea to implement it.

Wordpress Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/

Comment: Per a comment above, I have tried switching themes to the Twenty Ten theme, and the plugin works just fine. I'm about to start reading your posts in a moment...

Comment: Yes, so as I said, it seems to be something relative to the theme. With the twenty ten theme, the email address login works just fine and all plugins show properly. Of course, switching back to the theme I want to use, they fail. So where has this gotten me? Where can I look now?

Comment: @Honus Wagner: What theme are you using?

Comment: If its working with the other theme then your problem is the theme you're using. Like @Lars said It's probably something the theme owner forgot to do in the validation part. You should go thru your functions.php file. But it would help if we knew which theme you're using. You're likely to find your issue in the functions.php as most people store their custom code and hooks in that file. You should be looking for the hook that is modifying the registration process and/or login process. You can post those parts here so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Zubair1 I fixed it. It was a flaw in the theme that I had customized myself, but it turned out that some logins were not satisfying the if condition that was supposed to make the plugins work.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is coded without correctly validating usernames or overfiltering, it might crash before it reaches the plugin. Could you tell us a bit more on the theme and the plugin you use?